# How do I target Ajax Loader Throbber in CSS?

Tags: 7

I recently installed [Ajax Loader](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_loader) and it working great. However, I need some custom styling so, I can display the loading throbber in the center of the screen.

I can write my own CSS, But can't find the target class of Ajax Loader.

Looking forward for any help on this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target the overlay you can use .ajax-progress and to target the throbber you can use .ajax-throbber.

Something like this would position the throbber on the center of the screen:

```
.ajax-progress {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999999;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.ajax-throbber {
  left: 0;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ipwa, That's what I was looking for.

Comment: It's also good to add `overflow: auto` for the odd case when fixed content goes off screen, it allows for scrollbars so it isn't completely unreachable. It's not likely to happen if the throbber is small but it's still good practice.